# Ввод матрицы Си

Tags: c, матрицы, файловый-ввод-вывод

В программе необходимо заменить все числа матрицы, кратные 7, на максимальный элемент этой матрицы. Матрица находится в файле. До данного фрагмента корректно находится максимальный элемент max, в представленном фрагменте должна производиться замена чисел в файле, но файл не изменяется, хотя цикл находит числа, кратные 7, и fprintf возвращает значение 1.

```
fseek (input_file, 0, SEEK_SET);
while (!feof(input_file))
{
    fscanf(input_file, "%d", &m);
    cur_p = ftell(input_file) + 1;
    if (m % 7 == 0)
    {
        fprintf (input_file, "%d", max);
        fseek (input_file, cur_p, SEEK_SET);
    }
}
```

Comment: Что-то меня fseek напрягает. fprintf что ли не сдвигает указатель позиции в файле? Поскольку весь код не видно, то понять что там не так сложнее. И название странное input_file. Есть ввод и вывод, если в файл, то это вывод.

Comment: Ты хочешь затереть файл сразу, на сколько я понял. У тебя так не получится. Если у тебя там матрица, то проще всего будет записать её в массив (динамический), изменить как тебе нужно, а затем открыть этот файл уже для записи, и затереть его.